# RxJava - map different functions after a groupBy

Tags: java, functional-programming, rx-java, reactive-programming, rx-java2

Let's say I have an Observable emitting Integers. I would like to add 1 to all odd numbers and subtract 1 to all even numbers.

What would be a clean way of achieving this with RxJava?

I am struggling to understand how to achieve this with `groupBy` as I can't see a clean way to get `odd` and `even` Observable back after the `groupBy`, to then map a different function to each of them (and maybe merge them after).

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about simply mapping them conditionally?

```java
Observable.range(1, 10)
    .map(v -> {
       if (v % 2 == 0) {
           return v - 1;
       }
       return v + 1;
    })
    .subscribe(System.out::println)
```

Using `groupBy` is more involved:

```java
Observable.range(1, 10)
    .groupBy(v -> v % 2 == 0)
    .flatMap(group -> {
        if (group.getKey()) {
           return group.map(v -> v + 1);
        }
        return group.map(v -> v - 1);
    })
    .subscribe(System.out::println);
```

Comment: yes, this would work with my example. I was wondering if there is another way of doing so using native operators by separating the 2 streams instead, as in more complex scenarios (i.e. there are multiple different mapping functions to apply on each grouped stream, and maybe each stream could be again groupedBy too) I am not sure this will be a good option anymore.

Comment: I've extended the answer with a `groupBy` example, but beyond that, it depends what you try to achieve with each group.

Comment: Thanks @akarnokd ! I will create another question tomorrow with my more complex scenario to see if there is a way to simplify that too. I've just started to play with rxjava and want to validate that I am actually thinking reactive :)

Comment: hi @akarnokd, I created a question explaining in more detail what I am doing with each group, I would love to hear your opinion: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51399925/is-rxjava-a-good-fit-for-branching-workflows/51403928#51403928

thank you for your help!