# Is RxJava a good fit for branching workflows?

Tags: java, functional-programming, rx-java, reactive-programming, rx-java2

I am using RxJava to process some notifications that we pull from a queue.

RxJava seemed to work fine with a simple workflow, now with new requirements coming in, the flow is growing in complexity with more branches (please see below picture as a reference)
[image: workflow]
I tried to exemplify the flow with a small unit test:

```
@Test
public void test() {
    Observable.range(1, 100)
        .groupBy(n -> n % 3)
        .toMap(GroupedObservable::getKey)
        .flatMap(m1 -> {
            Observable<Integer> ones1 = m1.get(0);
            Observable<Integer> twos1 = m1.get(1).map(n -> n - 10);
            Observable<Integer> threes = m1.get(2).map(n -> n + 100);
            Observable<Integer> onesAndTwos = Observable.merge(ones1, twos1)
                .map(n -> n * 3)
                .groupBy(n -> n % 2)
                .toMap(GroupedObservable::getKey)
                .flatMap(m2 -> {
                    Observable<Integer> ones2 = m2.get(0).map(n -> n * 10);
                    Observable<Integer> twos2 = m2.get(1).map(n -> n * 100);
                    return Observable.merge(ones2, twos2);
                });
                return Observable.merge(onesAndTwos, threes).map(n -> n +1);
        })
        .subscribe(System.out::println);
}
```

Whilst it's still technically achievable to use RxJava, I am now wondering if it's a good choice, as to formalise the branching I had to do 2 level of nesting inside the main `flatMap`, which doesn't seem really neat.

Would this be the right way of describing a workflow like above? Or RxJava is not a good fit for branching workflows?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Note that there is nothing constraining you to produce an Rx graph like this in a single expression.  You can just as easily store the observables for internal points in the process in variables or fields and then use those separately.  That could let you break this flow apart into clearer modules, rather than showing it as a monolithic whole, which is at least a little intimidating.

Comment: That is true. But I was also wondering if there is a better way of handling branches within RxJava, maybe with native operators. At the end the main point is that after a `groupBy` I need to have a handle to all groups at once, so I can manipulate them together. That's why I am using `toMap`, but it's also what then creates the nesting. Maybe there is a better way?

Answer (score 0):

The grouping observable is the right way to go AFAIK. Personally, if anything in your picture between "split by a type" and "merge everything", is async, doing this in RX definitely has a lot of advantages like retry logic, buffering, error handling, backpressure, etc.. If it's regular non-async code it's a personal preference I guess. You could do it using RX, but you can also do everything between "split by a type" and "merge everything" using regular synchronous code.

Whatever way you chose, splitting up the code to make it more readable is always a good idea so you can "read the flow" as easy as we can read the image you attached.

Comment: Thanks, I agree with you but I am still struggling to get if RxJava is good for branching flows. In the example above I am using `toMap` to be able to reason with all groups at once in the next stage, so I can then merge them together. I've just learnt that `toMap` is blocking as it needs to resolve all the keys to be able to emit the map, which is not great at all. The `groupBy` is the way to go, but then is very difficult to work with these new groups all at once so you can do other stuff with them. I still can't see a clean way for coding branching flows as in my example with RxJava.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve. You basically can chose three flavours for handling the items: blocking `toMap` and get everything, non-blocking stream with `groupBy` to get it streaming, or put a buffer/window between somewhere so you can get everything in batches (and potentially do stuff "all at once" as you mentioned).

Answer (score 0):

Just an idea for another approach which may work for you: Instead of grouping/toMap, you could multicast the source and handle the branches individually.

Example:

```
@Test
public void multicastingShare() {
    final Observable<Integer> sharedSource = Observable.range(1, 10)
            .doOnSubscribe(dummy -> System.out.println("subscribed"))
            .share();
    // split by some criteria
    final Observable<String> oddItems = sharedSource
            .filter(n -> n % 2 == 1)
            .map(odd -> "odd: " + odd)
            .doOnNext(System.out::println);
    final Observable<String> evenItems = sharedSource
            .filter(n -> n % 2 == 0)
            .map(even -> "even: " + even)
            .doOnNext(System.out::println);

    // recombine the individual streams at some point
    Observable.concat(oddItems, evenItems)
            .subscribe(result -> System.out.println("result: " + result));
}
```

This [video](https://vimeo.com/190922794) may be be helpful (at least the first 15 min)