# RxJava: merge() changes the order of the emitted items?

Tags: java, functional-programming, rx-java, reactive-programming, rx-java2

Look at these 2 small tests:

```
@Test
public void test1() {
    Observable.range(1, 10)
        .groupBy(v -> v % 2 == 0)
        .flatMap(group -> {
            if (group.getKey()) {
                return group;
            }
            return group;
        })
        .subscribe(System.out::println);
}

@Test
public void test2() {
    Observable.range(1, 10)
        .groupBy(v -> v % 2 == 0)
        .toMap(g -> g.getKey())
        .flatMapObservable(m -> Observable.merge(
            m.get(true),
            m.get(false)))
        .subscribe(System.out::println);
}
```

I was expecting both to return a list of numbers in the same order, so:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
```

but the second example returns

```
2 4 6 8 10 1 3 5 7 9
```

instead.

It seems that on the second example the `merge` is doing a `concat` instead, in fact if I change it to a `concat`, the result is the same.

What am I missing?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically `flatMap` and `merge` do not guarantee the order of the emitted items.

From [flatMap](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/flatmap.html) doc:

> Note that FlatMap merges the emissions of these Observables, so that they may interleave.

From [merge](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/merge.html) doc:

> Merge may interleave the items emitted by the merged Observables (a similar operator, Concat, does not interleave items, but emits all of each source Observable’s items in turn before beginning to emit items from the next source Observable).

Quote from this [SO Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38904515/6287240):

> In your case, with single-element, static streams, it is not making any real difference (but in theory, merge could output words in random order and still be valid according to spec)

If you need a guaranteed order use `concat*` instead.

## First example

It works like this:

- when `1` is emitted the `groupBy` operator will create a `GroupedObservable` with key `false`

  - `flatMap` will output the items from this observable - which is currently only `1`
- when `2` is emitted the `groupBy` operator will create a `GroupedObservable` with key `true`

  - `flatMap` will now also output the items from this 2nd `GroupedObservable` - which is currently `2`
- when `3` is emitted the `groupBy` operator will add it to the existing `GroupedObservable` with key `false` and `flatMap` will output this item right away
- when `4` is emitted the `groupBy` operator will add it to the existing `GroupedObservable` with key `true` and `flatMap` will output this item right away
- etc.

It may help you to add some more logging:

```
    Observable.range(1, 10)
            .groupBy(v -> v % 2 == 0)
            .doOnNext(group -> System.out.println("key: " + group.getKey()))
            .flatMap(group -> {
                if (group.getKey()) {
                    return group;
                }
                return group;
            })
            .subscribe(System.out::println);
```

Then the output is:

```
key: false
1
key: true
2
3
...
```

## The second example

This is quite different, because `toMap` will block until the upstream completes:

- when `1` is emitted the `groupBy` operator will create a `GroupedObservable` with key `false`

  - `toMap` will add this `GroupedObservable` to the internal map and uses the key `false` (the same key as the `GroupedObservable` has)
- when `2` is emitted the `groupBy` operator will create a `GroupedObservable` with key `true`

  - `toMap` will add this `GroupedObservable` to the internal map and uses the key `true` (the same key as the `GroupedObservable` has) - so now the map has 2 `GroupedObservables`
- the following numbers are added to the corresponding `GroupedObservables` and when the source completes, the`toMap` operator is done and will pass the map to the next operator
- in `flatMapObservable` you use the map to create a new observable where you first add the even elements (key = `true`) and then the odd elements (key = `false`)

Also here you could add some more logging:

```
    Observable.range(1, 10)
            .groupBy(v -> v % 2 == 0)
            .doOnNext(group -> System.out.println("key: " + group.getKey()))
            .toMap(g -> g.getKey())
            .doOnSuccess(map -> System.out.println("map: " + map.size()))
            .flatMapObservable(m -> Observable.merge(
                    m.get(true),
                    m.get(false)
            ))
            .subscribe(System.out::println);
```

Then the output is:

```
key: false
key: true
map: 2
2
4
6
8
10
1
3
5
7
9
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, but I still don't get why the `merge` inside `flatMapObservable` is not preserving the order. I get now that `toMap` is blocking, as it needs to know the keys of the map in order to emit it for the next stages. `In your case, with single-element, static streams, it is not making any real difference` but the 2 Observable inside the newly map are not single-element, are they? Also I am not sure what `static` means in this context. The definition of `merge` says that elements might interleave, which is what I would expect in this case, instead is behaving like a `concat`.

Comment: `in flatMapObservable you use the map to create a new observable where you first add the even elements (key = true) and then the odd elements (key = false)` I think this would be true if I was doing `concat`, but I am doing a `merge` instead.

Comment: Right, the 2 Observables in your map have 5 elements each - but they are `static` (i.e. not depending on some timing) - in other words: the streams are already fully defined and all elements are known. `toMap` the source stream has already completed and the Observables in the map can output all their elements immediately when subscribed to.

Comment: ad 2nd comment: Well, in this case it is just coincidence that `merge` behaves the same as `concat`. So this `merge` implementation obviously subscribes to the first observable (what you pass as 1st parameter)  and processes all its data and then subscribes to the 2nd and processes all data of the 2nd observable. But as mentioned at the top: this is not guaranteed by `merge`.

Comment: Well, coincidence may be the wrong word. But what I want to express is, that the behavior of `merge`, that we see is implementation dependent. In other words: other Rx implementations may have a different behavior  - or even a newer version of RxJava may have a different behavior.

Comment: thanks for your further explanation! clear now :) so `toMap` has quite big implications on the whole stream, as everything must be resolved before going on. I'm now wondering how you can reason with all the groups in one place in RxJava without having to use `toMap` as I am doing in the second example. I posted another question about this if you'd like to have a look :) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51399925/is-rxjava-a-good-fit-for-branching-workflows